# Minecraft 1.10 Not Switching To Forge

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher, minecraft-forge

When I open up my Minecraft launcher, it seems to work fine. However, when I try to change my profile to Forge, it stays on Minecraft 1.10. When I launch Minecraft using Forge, it still stays on Minecraft 1.10. Please help.[image: Screenshot Of Launcher]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we do not offer tech support for modified Minecraft. This includes Forge. I recommend asking the Forge forums.

Comment: @DJPirtu this isn't Tech Support as it isn't a crash.  All he needs to do is Edit Profile>Version> and select forge version.

Comment: @Alex I admit, I could be wrong. If you think that's the solution, feel free to post the answer.

Comment: @DJPirtu It's not even a bug. You just need to click a few buttons.

Comment: @Alex Since you are so sure about this, please. Post the answer. Help the asker. If I'm wrong, my close vote will be turned by other voters _and_ you're likely to get the upvotes on your answer.

Answer (score 9):

1) Select your Forge profile and `Edit Profile`.

2) In editation, be sure you have those values right:

- (OPTIONAL, but VERY USEFUL) **Game directory** : It is VERY good to store different versions in different folders, because they *conflict with each other* (1.9 with 1.8, vanilla with Forge etc) - the thing is that even one mutual config with different values inside can stop the game from launching - that is why you should put there some custom directory, for example I have `.minecraft/ForgeProfiles/<version>`
- (OPTIONAL) Forge installer will always override "Forge" profile, it is good to **rename the profile** if you will install more versions in future (also it is good for tracking what version is what)
- CHECK YOUR **VERSION selection**. This can be very crucial. If there is selected "`Use latest version`", then new released version of the game just overrided the one you were using. If you want to have Forge in that profile, reselect it to the build you want. THIS alone can do the thing you describe, there won't be anything else to setup that will affect this.

When you create new profile, you do it by duplicating your actual one. If that one had the "latest" selection, there it is why the new one has it, too.

As you can see, this whole thing is usable for ALL versions, you can select beta builds or pre-releases the same way, as Forge. If you used Forge Installer, you will have corresponding Forge versions just in the selection as any other versions.

Here is a picture of mentioned and working setup:

[image]