# I cannot find my mods folder in my .minecraft file

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I have tried various tips, such as:

- *"make a new 'mods' folder in your thing and put your mod in"*
- *"it automatically creates a new folder for mods on it's own after booting up stuff like Forge"*

I am running on Windows 10 and I am using Forge for 1.12.1

Any advice?

Comment: Do you know where your `.minecraft` folder is? If no, does typing `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` into the Windows Explorer path bar work?

Comment: Yes, I have entered my .minecraft folder to check, and theres no mods folder.

I created one on my own to see if all the other advice pieces worked, and I couldn't find my mod in the list after putting my mod file in the "mods" folder I created and booted up the game.

Comment: So you created the folder (called `mods` without capital letters), put your mods in it that were compatible with the Forge version you installed, started the Forge profile in the launcher and it still didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I created a mods folder (no capitals) and put my modpack folder in it. I booted up the game on my Forge profile, then checked my Mods list and it wasn't there.

Comment: Modpack? What do you mean by that? There often are packs that are not meant for a manual installation with Forge, but for a different launcher or something like that. What pack is it and where did you get it from?

Comment: If you are installing a mod pack, 90% of them aren't done that way. There should be installers or launchers included when you download a mod pack. Unless the author of the mod pack instructs you to do so, dragging the entire mod pack folder into the `mods` folder won't do anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: Some useful tips: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270912/minecraft-1-10-not-switching-to-forge/270924#270924

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure that Minecraft Forge is **actually installed**. You can check by starting Minecraft, and checking if there is a button labeled "mods" on the title screen. If there isn't, then your problem is with the way you installed Forge.

If you do see the button, you can enter your .minecraft folder and create a new folder called "mods". Then copy and paste all mods there.

However, you mentioned in the comments of your original post that you already did this. You also mentioned that you are installing a *mod-pack* and not a mod. Depending on which mod-pack you are installing, this process could be completely different.

If the mod-pack was designed for the [Technic Launcher](https://www.technicpack.net/download), you can simply download that launcher and search for your mod-pack from within it. This will automatically install it. If your mod-pack was not designed the Technic Launcher, check the page where you downloaded the pack from for additional instructions.

If you still can't figure it out, try searching both Google and YouTube for `[Mod-pack name] install`.